# Can I use WebRTC to broadcasting text (one to many)

Tags: text, webrtc, broadcasting

How can I using WebRTC to broadcasting the text to many users? I try to use [this](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/DataChannel) but it cannot use for many users.

Comment: I think that your more after [`websockets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) rather than webRTC

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC uses peer-to-peer connection, but in some cases such connection type can't be installed just by using STUN.  For such situations you have to use TURN. For example this server https://github.com/coturn/coturn

Try to google free servers and add them to the your servers config. But much better to install own server with public ip